# Notation for switching dimensions

Tags: soft-question, notation, convention

Is there a standard (or commonly used) symbol for the function that switches dimensions of a set?

Formally, I am looking for a symbol for the function $f:\mathcal{P}(A \times B) \to \mathcal{P}(B \times A)$ defined by 
$$
f(S)=\{(b,a) \mid (a,b) \in S \}
$$

Alternatively, a symbol for the function $g:A \times B \to B \times A$ would also be helpful, where $g$ is defined by
$$
g(a,b)=(b,a)
$$

If there is no standard notation for $f$, reasonable suggestions on what *could* be a good symbol (or name) for $f$ are also helpful!

Comment: Why not just defining $f$ function as u did, is not sufficient?

Comment: If you set $f(a,b) = (b,a)$ then you can reuse $f$ for the map $\cal P(A \times B) \to \mathcal P(B \times A)$. It is common to write $f(S)$ for $\{ f(x) \mid x \in S \}$.

Comment: @Pookaros I could do that (using the name $f$), but I was hoping there was some convention for such a "common" function. Just as $\pi$ is usually used to denote a projection.